# What does "perfect" in say past perfect imply?

Tags: present-perfect

Many verb tenses such as "past perfect", "present perfect", and "future perfect" exist.

I understand what these tenses mean and when they should be used, but what does the word perfect imply? Are other tenses somehow not perfect?

Comment: _Perfect_ is an English rendering of the Lating grammatical term _perfectum_, which is the past participle of the verb _perficere_ 'do completely; finish', which comes from the verb _facere_ 'make, do'. So something is "perfect" in the linguistic sense if it is _done with, over, finished, all through,_ and _not continuing_. This was a separate tense (different endings) in Latin and still is in the Romance languages, where it's called the past or the preterite and contrasts with the "imperfect", which is like English past continuous in meaning, but still different endings in form.

Answer (score 2):

*Perfect* in this case has nothing to do with *perfection*. The name is an historical accident.

The Latin *perfectum* means *complete* or *finished*, and one of the Latin past tenses was named *perfectum* because it designated finished actions. Later, in the Baroque era, the earliest English grammarians were struggling to describe the language. They had no tool to hand but classical grammar*, so they borrowed the name *perfect* for our language's second past tense.

---

* Which they interpreted mostly at second hand, by way of French grammarians—and as John Lawler points out, Romance languages like French mostly retained some form of the Latin *perfectum*.

Comment: They borrowed it for constructions with _have_ plus `Past Participle`, which are not always past -- the use of this construction is more like the Greek perfect system than the Latin. (There's only one past tense in English, btw. :-)

Comment: @JohnLawler But they thought of it as a second past tense. Pickbourn 1789 seems to be the first to have recognized the present perfect as a 'present' tense. (Pickbourn distinguishes five present and five past tenses.)

Comment: Yes, as you pointed out, they wanted Latin models. As to what they thought of as tense, it's probably no sillier than modern Anglophone school "grammar".

Comment: @JohnLawler Let's be fair: the contemporary sense of *tense* is a mid-20th-century innovation. Jespersen in the 20s used *tense* in the same sense as Pickbourn, down to his distinction of 'simple' and 'compound' tenses.

Comment: Jespersen wanted to get his books published and into the school system. If you allow the perfect as a tense, you have to allow the progressive as a tense, too, because they're just the same: `Aux` + `Participle`, lined up in order. You could stop there and have English with only the present, the past, the present perfect, the past perfect, the present continuous, the past continuous, the present perfect continuous, and the past perfect continuous. Eight tenses. Except then somebody asks about the future tense. And the subjunctive tense. And the emphatic tense. And the conditional tense. And ..